# Android 8 hooking into permissions popup allow/deny event when ionic app launches

Tags: ionic-framework, permissions, android-8.0-oreo

When our ionic 1.x app launches on an android 8 (targetSdkVersion:26, Samsung S8 device), it displays a permissions popup

> Allow app to access photos, media and files on your device? Deny Allow

The popup is displayed before any of our app code runs so we suspect it is due to the permissions mentioned in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

We also use the fingerprint login plugin and when the permission popup and fingerprint login prompt overlaps, fingerprint login stops working (prompt stays open, does not log user in)

In an Ionic 1.x  app, is there a way to hook into the permission allowed/denied event so that we can delay the fingerprint until after user allow/denies permissions?

Or any other ideas on how to work around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup you are describing is a native Android runtime permissions dialog, which is displayed when a request for a permission is made at runtime. This dialog is not automatically displayed due to a `<uses-permission>` element being present in the manifest (although the relevant manifest entry must be present in order to request permission at runtime). So this dialog is being displayed because a plugin (I can't say exactly which one because you haven't explicitly listed your plugins) in your project is making the runtime request for that permission on app startup (which is not good practice).

Since the dialog is native, there's no way for you to "hook into it" without modifying the native plugin which is making the runtime request. My advice would be to fork that plugin and comment out the native permission request which is made on startup in your forked plugin version.

You could then either expose that permission request in your forked plugin as a plugin API method (if you know how to create Cordova plugins) or you could use a 3rd party plugin such as [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) or [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) to request the relevant permission at runtime. This would allow you to request the permission (i.e. show the dialog) only when you are ready to do so.

Comment: If we decide to request relevant permissions at runtime, how can we stop the permissions popup from displaying when app is launched? I removed all the code so that app.js looks like this
var app = angular
  .module("pcty", [])
  .run(function () {});

Still getting the popup.

Comment: Most likely the request is being made in the native Java layer by a plugin. Please provide a list of plugins in your project or a link to the plugin you suspect is making the request and I'll have a look at the source code.

Comment: The culprit was the filepath plugin, we were using an older version. We started removing suspected plugins one by one checked if the app still displayed the prompt. Removed the filepath plugin, permission popup went away.
Upgraded plugin version, issue resolved. Thanks for your help.